# C - use scanf to scan string into an array

Tags: c, arrays, string, visual-studio-2015, scanf

I am trying to make a program that uses one *scansf* function to get someones entire name at once and stores each letter in one layer of an array. 
For example what it should do if the name entered is "tim":

```
 array[0]=t
 array[1]=i
 array[2]=m
 array[3]=\0
```

i have read this in other threats but it doesn´t work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char array[256];
    scanf_s("%s", array);
    printf_s("%s", array);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives out this error message:

[image]

> English:
>   Exeption triggered at 0x0FAA0B5C 
>   access violation while writing position 0x01300000

Is it even possible to use the *scanf* function if yes how?
Or is there a better alternative?

---

Thank you by adding the buffer parameter **works**
code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

int main(void) {
    char array[256];
    scanf_s("%255s", array, 256);
    printf("%s", array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand German, but it looks like a crash. You probably get it because you're not using [`scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) correctly.

Comment: `scanf_s("%255s", array, 256);` You need to add buffer size parameter.

Comment: have you tried  scanf_s("%s", array,sizeof(array)); you can always set the buffersize how you want

Comment: You *must* pass the size of the buffer as an additional argument to `scanf_s`: `scanf_s( "%s", array, (unsigned) _countof( array ) );`

Comment: Per the documentation from MS, "Unlike `scanf` and `wscanf`, `scanf_s` and `wscanf_s` **require the buffer size to be specified** for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []".

Answer (score 1):

simply use scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char array[256];
    scanf("%s", array);
    printf("%s", array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: visual studio 2015 says >code C4996 'scanf' is unsave

Comment: may be visual studio restricts scanf function due to some security problems. You can use scanf_s.

Comment: make sure that the value you provided will goes under 256 charachters

Comment: @RDuich: `scanf` with the `%s` or `%[` specifiers *can* be unsafe, but you can work around it with an explicit field width in the specifier: `scanf( "%255s", array );

Comment: @RDuich yes `scanf` is unsafe, but for test programs it's good enough.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `scanf` without the `_s`. E.g.:

```
scanf("%s",array);
printf("%s\n", array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use scanf_s then have  a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)